# Modify an exist DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I would like to know if there is any way to get a DialogFragment just like `getFragmentByTag`?

I'll explain. I am using a dialog fragment to get some info from the user, then I set the info as a data of a child, of an Expandable ListView.

Then I created a button which allows the user to edit the child data.. I want to re-open the same DialogFragment and set the old data in the EditText fields.
this is my code:

```
NewExerciseChildFragment editExercise = new NewExerciseChildFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("groupPosition", groupPosition);
bundle.putString("exerciseName", exerciseName);
bundle.putDouble("weight", weight);
bundle.putInt("reps", reps);
bundle.putInt("sets", sets);

editExercise.setArguments(bundle);
editExercise.show(getFragmentManager(), "showEditedExercise");
```

Problem is, I create a new DialogFragment, which means I wouldn't edit the data but add another child instead.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation you have two options for displaying your `DialogFragment`, either as a **Dialog** ("pop-up") or **Embedding**

> **Selecting Between Dialog or Embedding**
>
> A DialogFragment can still optionally be used as a normal fragment, if
>   desired. This is useful if you have a fragment that in some cases
>   should be shown as a dialog and others embedded in a larger UI. This
>   behavior will normally be automatically selected for you based on how
>   you are using the fragment, but can be customized with
>   setShowsDialog(boolean).
>
> ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment

**Dialogs** are meant to be used as a "pop up"*, which is typically destroyed after dismissal. This option would require passing a reference to the data/model/object residing in the `ExapandableListView` (or some child of it, as you mentioned). This object would need to expose all of the necessary setters/getters for it's values/state to be manipulated by the `DialogFragment`.

If you do go this route, then why not obtain the initial data (of exercise metrics) the same way - by passing a reference to a blank object - unless there is another reason to have a special case for initially obtaining the data not mentioned? This way, your mechanism to both obtain and edit the data would be identical.

A good article for passing object references via a bundle/parcel is here https://medium.com/@hamidgh/sending-objects-to-fragment-naive-question-is-it-sent-by-value-ddaaa19fa42d.

**Embedding** would allow the user to edit the data in place, eliminating the need for a pop-up, but this may require more space than is available since the data/fields would have to be large enough to edit with reasonable ease.

However, using what you already have, is there any reason why you cannot simply return the edited data, just as is done when it is initially entered, you seem to be using the `Bundle` properly to send the values back to the dialog for editing, so I see no problem there?